# Customize FosUserTemplate

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override FOSUser Template and add some html items to my pages, I got this error :

> Unexpected token "end of template" of value "" ("end of statement block" expected).

here is the base.html.twig page:

> ```
>   <!DOCTYPE html>
>   <html lang="en">
>   <head>
>   <meta charset="utf-8">
>   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
>   <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other 
>   head content must come *after* these tags -->
>  <meta name="description" content="">
>  <meta name="author" content="">
>  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
>  {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
>  <link rel="stylesheet" 
> href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
> {% stylesheets
> "css/myStyle.css"
> %}
> <link rel="stylesheets" href="{{ asset_url }}">
>
> <title>{% block title %}Hello!{% endblock %}</title>
>
>
> <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
> <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
>
> <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
> <!--[if lt IE 9]>
> <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">
> </script>
> <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
> </script>
> <![endif]-->    </head>
>  <body>
> {% block topnav %}
> {% include '::topnav.html.twig' %}
> {% endblock %}
> <div class="container">
> {% block content %}{% endblock %}    </div>
>
>
> <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
> ================================================== -->
> <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
> <script 
>    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}

this is the layout.html.twig page :

> {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
>
> {% block content %}
>
> ```
> <div>
>     {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
>         {{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': 
>  app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }} |
>         <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
>             {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
>         </a>
>     {% else %}
>         <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">{{ 
>        'layout.login'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a>
>     {% endif %}
> </div>
>
> {% if app.request.hasPreviousSession %}
>     {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
>         {% for message in messages %}
>             <div class="flash-{{ type }}">
>                 {{ message }}
>             </div>
>         {% endfor %}
>     {% endfor %}
> {% endif %}
>
> <div>
>     {% block fos_user_content %}
>     {% endblock fos_user_content %}
> </div>
>
> {% endblock %}
> ```

Comment: Are you sure these are the correct content of the files you specified? You should get an error with `{% stylesheets "css/myStyle.css" %}`!

Comment: it is important to valid answer if it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style sheet must be declared as follow

```
    {% stylesheets
        'path/to/style.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

your ***endstylesheets*** is missing

Have a look there 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

Refer to official documentation :

How to override templates : http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

How to override FormType : http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html